# Can DLC for the PC version of Dragon Age 2 be installed mid-game?

Tags: pc, dragon-age-2

For the PC version specifically, can i install the Black Emporium, load my current game (started with no DLC) and continue it, with the Black Emporium available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you will get a new quest to go visit the place. For other item related dlcs you will get a 'special delivery box' in  your home.